# Stroke width within viewBox

Tags: svg

I use viewBox to simulate percentage values for the path like that:

```
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
```

which means that one unit has 5px. That works as expected except that the stroke is always 5px width. How can I set width of the stroke to be always 1px ? I've already tried `stroke-width:1px` which didn't work.

Comment: stroke-width:0.2px perhaps?

Comment: @Robert what will happen if I change the size of the svg to for example 1000X1000 the stroke will be 2px width ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use vector-effect.

```
<line ... stroke-width="1px" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#NonScalingStroke